# How to join nested columns in spark with usingColumns

Tags: apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes that I would like to join.

DF1:

```
root
 |-- myStruct: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- region: long (nullable = true)
 |-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
```

DF2:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- region: long (nullable = true)
 |-- second_name: string (nullable = true)
```

My join statement is

```
df1.join(df2, Seq("id", "region"), "leftouter")
```

but that fails with

```
USING column `id` cannot be resolved on the left side of the join. The left-side columns: myStruct, first_name
```

I am running Spark 2.2 on Scala

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.` notation to select an element from `struct` column. so to select `id` from *df1* you will have to do `myStruct.id` and to select `region` you have to use `myStruct.region`.

And *since the column names to be used are not same* you can use `===` notation for comparison as

```
df1.join(df2, df1("myStruct.id") === df2("id") && df1("myStruct.region") === df2("region"), "leftouter")
```

You should have the joined *dataframe* with following *schema*

```
root
 |-- myStruct: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- region: long (nullable = false)
 |-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- region: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- second_name: string (nullable = true)
```

You can *drop* the unnecessary columns after join or *select* only needed columns after join

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 2):

This is because in DF1, `id` is an element of column `myStruct` which is of type struct. In order to join you can do something like,

```
val df = df1
.withColumn("id", col("myStruct.id"))
.withColumn("region", col("myStruct.region"))

df.join(df2, Seq("id", "region"), "leftouter")
```

This essentially extracts `id` and `region` from the struct column.