# Is there an efficient way to join two large Datasets with (deeper) nested array field?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Apache Spark with Java to join two big datasets. I'll try to give an example pair of datasets to lay out my problem. Let's say I have Table A and Table B, with schemas that look like:

```
Table A
root
|-- shopper_name: string
|-- shopping_list: struct
|---|-- date: date 
|---|-- shopping_items: array
|---|---|-- item_name: string
```

and

```
Table B
root
|-- item_name: string
|-- item_price: double
```

So I want to join these two tables on the deeply nested field `item_name` so that I can work out the price of each shopper's shopping list. The problem is that I can't just create an additional column on Table A called `item_name`, as there could be many `item_name` objects within the `shopping_items` array.

One simple solution would be to explode Table A (de-normalise it), so that I have a single row for every `item_name`, do the join, then group by `shopper_name` and sum.

My question is: does Spark (and more specifically Spark for Java ) have a better way of doing this that doesn't feel so inefficient? Can Spark do this sort of explosion on two datasets with hundreds of millions/billions of rows and parallelise it nicely?

Comment: pls show your .explain

Comment: This is theoretical. I don't have any code or operations to `.explain` but the schema and example problem above should suffice.

Comment: But clarify the term deeply nested? I missed the array

Comment: Well the list that contains the join term might be very far down inside my struct. Far enough down that exploding the struct fully would create a much larger number of rows than I had within my original Dataset.

Comment: Is not the number of occurrences  of nesting more a deciding factor? In any event you may need to explode more than once. If you do not know how many levels in advance I would talk to provider of data.

Comment: From the example provided I could not discern a deep nesting ...

Comment: I am adding to the answer - I think this map help, but I am not sure as the question is not entirely clear.

Answer (score 1):

**With nesting and no repeating groups**

You are dealing with a JOIN on DFs with one element being a column from a type struct.

> There is no issue doing that, i.e. you do not need to explode at all.
>   You just need the . approach to get to that column.

Execution issue are also not evident if you have sufficient resources allocated and fit within partitioning limits.

For guidance you can look at this post on this site: [How to join nested columns in spark with usingColumns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52013371/how-to-join-nested-columns-in-spark-with-usingcolumns)

**With a Nested Array**

However, your theory is correct in that with a nested array that needs atomic JOINing you must use an explode. It's that simple. May be more than once.

Once again, no issues with performance provided enough resources and suitable partition sizes. Just takes time.

***EDIT - although thrust of question not entirely clear***

If you are concerned that one needs to explode all the way down to desired element level, then that is not always the case. Consider this two level structure:

```
root
 |-- director: string (nullable = true)
 |-- films: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- actors: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

You can just explode 1) directly down to desired level first and then 2) possibly issue a final 2nd explode if that level was nested as well.

But I am not sure if this is your concern. POINT is therefore: navigate to lowest level, explode and than possibly another explode - if required, but it should be at max only two iterations required.

```
val flattened2 = df.select($"director", explode($"films.actors").as("actors_flat"))

val flattened3 = flattened2.select($"director", explode($"actors_flat").as("actors_flattened"))
```

With a level deeper as well as well ok, but there are some finnicky Spark things for sure to consider, e.g. successive DFs and column naming issues that seem to rear their ugly head here and elsewhere.

**General**

For Large - Large table JOINs (is this really the case here?) there is no quick efficient fix. MergeScan is normally what is used behind the scenes from my experience, but things keep changing per release.

Comment: But what if it's a _list_ of nested columns from a type struct? So one row might contain six "joinable" fields, but the next row contains seven, the next row contains one, and so on.

The example you've provided contains a "definite" subcolumn and doesn't work for my shopping list problem.